# Building a 700c bike. Hub sizes

Tags: frames, hub, bike-fit, cyclocross, front

Trying to build a bike on a cyclocross frame. So the wheel will be 700c. Need hubs. Fork size is 100x15 with thru axle. Rear drops size 142mm x 12mm thru axle also. So it means I need any hubs which will fit these sizes? Because I know that these standards are mostly for mountain bikes, and know nothing about how they fit the 700c wheels.

Thinking of buying a pair of Hope Pro 4 or a pair of DT Swiss 350s MTB hub for rear and front.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the rim is 700c, any hubs with the thru axle dimensions you mentioned will work.

> Fork size is 100x15 with thru axle. Rear drops size 142мм x 12мм thru axle also. So it means i need any hubs which will fit these sizes? Because i know that these standarts are mostly for mountain bikes, and know nothing about how they fit the 700c wheels.

This is actually not quite true. 142x12mm is a common spec for the rear hub on current drop bar bikes with disc brakes. The vast majority of these bikes have thru axles. I think that many, possibly the majority, of drop bar bikes may have 100x12mm thru axles in the front, but 100x15 isn't unheard of.

Right now, I believe Boost spacing (i.e. 110x15mm front, 148x12mm rear) characterizes mountain bikes. I have no idea if drop bar bikes will adopt this spacing. Boost spacing improves the bracing angle of the hubs. It will increase wheel stiffness and strength. I'm a very light road and gravel rider, and I don't ride MTBs, so I have no idea if this performance gain is actually meaningful on MTBs. I have no idea if it will produce a meaningful performance gain for drop bar bikes, either.

Comment: 142mm rear spacing is showing up on some drop bar bikes with disc brakes and through axles.

Comment: Boost spacing is also generally associated with much bigger tire sizes ie. 27.5+ at least. (i.e. 2.8 inch tires and up).

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog That's a good point. Cyclocross bikes only need space for ~35mm tires